# Are there any obvious bottlenecks in my MariaDB UPDATE?

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I have a MariaDB table with 28 million rows. I need to update all the rows (locally) with a new value in a column. This is the code in Python to batch update:

```
update_query = "UPDATE table SET column = %s WHERE `index` = %s"
%time cursor.executemany(update_query, update_data)
```

`column` has an index, and `index` is the primary key.

When I use a batch of 100,000 rows, it takes 50 seconds to run the `executemany()`. I am not sure if this is very slow or normal. And if it's slow, I don't know where to start for speeding it up.

Comment: You could start by playing with smaller and bigger batch sizes. How long are the keys?

Comment: If `column` is indexed then every update will also require an update to the index. You might find it faster to drop the index on `column` while you perform this update, then recreate it after you're finished.

Comment: I guess you need to divide this task to parallel tasks. Take 28 million rows and divide them to tasks that will update 100k rows or less and run them in different threads

Comment: @user207421 The time to complete is pretty consistent no matter the batch size. 100,000 takes about 10 times as long as 10,000. I'm not sure what you mean by keys, though.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular That's true, but I'll need them indexed to use them, so wouldn't the total time to update an unindexed table then index be pretty similar to just updating while they are already indexed?

Comment: @AskhatBilyalov Hmm, running multiple `executemany`'s in parallel? I'll look into that.

Comment: @Dima Not necessarily. If you perform 100,000 updates on the table that will require 100,000 updates to the index. Reindexing the whole table will just update it once, albeit one major update. This is not a guaranteed fix, but you _might_ find it faster. Try it and see.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Will do, I'll let you know what kind of times I get.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Oh, shoot, I just realized that I need the index there because my script first selects 100,000 rows that are still NULL, and then updates those values. The initial SELECT now takes a very long time. (But the UPDATE takes 3 seconds now FWIW.)

Comment: How long are the keys in the index? This is not a trick question. Shouldn’t have to ask it twice.

Comment: @Dima Don’t make personal remarks here. I asked you for the length of the key, and you still haven’t answered it. Third time of asking. I didn’t ask how long is an integer, or what it’s maximum value is.

Comment: @user207421 Your comment "shouldn't have to ask it twice" is basically the definition of rude and condescending. You seem to enjoy the feeling of knowing something I don't, given you won't explain what you're asking for when it's obvious I don't know. I'm not interested in your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike `INSERT`, `executemany()` can't automatically batch `UPDATE` queries, so the bottleneck is performing 100,000 queries.

Instead, use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`. This will be batched automatically.

```
update_query = 'INSERT INTO table (column, index) VALUES (%s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column = VALUES(column)'
%time cursor.executemany(update_query, update_data)
```

Comment: Great, that did bring it down from 50 seconds to 35 seconds! I was hoping I could get it to more like 5 seconds, and I just wasn't sure if what I'm getting are reasonable times, or if there is something wrong with my server. But still, this is a big improvement, thanks!

Comment: you can try batch inserting all the indexes and new values into a temp table then doing a single update joining that.  fwiw if it was doing 100000 individual updates before and now is batching the inserts, I would have expected a much bigger improvement than 50s to 35s

Comment: @ysth ok thanks, I'll give that a try.

Comment: At some point you're limited by the I/O speed to actually update all those rows.